# Young Adult book about a Teen Witch Girl

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult, witches

I read this book and I think it was the second in the series. I was in middle school reading this in like 2007.

It's about a teen witch in HS I think. She is currently dating her ex boyfriend's older brother. She changes her clothes with magic in the morning before school. She can use batteries for teleportation spells. She has a mom and a younger sister. She starts going to this witch school or something at night. She meets a warlock boy. All the witches are supposed to have a ceremony on Halloween but the warlocks aren't deemed as important so they have their ceremonies at other times.

It was called something like "Frogs, broomsticks, and boys" or something like that. I have tried countless searches but no result for what I'm looking for.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where did you read this?  Was it a paperback, a hardcover or an e-book?  What do you mean by "second in the series of IDK?"

Answer (score 5):

Possibly [Frogs & French Kisses](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/26212.Frogs_French_Kisses) by Sarah Mlynowski. This is book two in the [Magic in Manhattan](https://www.goodreads.com/series/40586-magic-in-manhattan) series and the first book is [Bras and Broomsticks](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/26210.Bras_Broomsticks), which may be where you are connecting frogs and broomsticks. The timing is right as well since it was published in 2006.

[image: Frogs & French Kisses]

The only thing is that the protagonist, *Rachel*, cannot perform magic. It's her younger sister *Miri* that has magic powers.

In the book Rachel and her boyfriend *Raf* have split up and she asks Miri to cast a love spell to get Raf back. The spell goes wrong and Raf's brother *Will* falls in love with Rachel instead.